# MongoClient() is successful, but Database(MongoClient(), dbName) returns NoneType

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm trying to implement a MongoDB connection handler, but am running into an issue where my [Database](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database) call returns `None`, even though my `MongoClient()` call is successful.

```
#mongoconn.py

from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.database import Database

class MongoConnection():
    mongoconn = None

    def __init__(self, db=None, collection=None, endpoint=None):
        self.mongodb = db
        self.mongocollection = collection
        self.mongoendpoint = endpoint
        mongoconn = self.__mongo_connect()

    def __mongo_connect(self):
        if self.mongoendpoint is not None: 
            mc = MongoClient(host=self.mongoendpoint, port=27017, document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)
            print mc    #successful object
            return Database(mc)
        else: 
            mc = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017, document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)
            print mc    #successful object
            return Database(mc, self.mongodb)

m1 = MongoConnection("torbot")

print m1.mongoconn    # None
```

I can see that this collection `torbot` does exist, so I don't believe that's the issue:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0
use torbot
switched to db torbot
db.requests.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584f7e17bc1d1b7f37d54756"), "requestor" : "ctote", "request" : "Scott Pilgrim Vs The World" }
```

But I can't find any debug options to see why the call to `Database(mc, self.mongodb)` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoconn` is a class attribute to access it in the `__init__` method you need to prefix it with the class name or `self`. In your case you are doing `self.mongoconn` will create an instance attribute which is probably not what you want so what you need is `MongoConnection.mongoconn = self.__mongo_connect()`. Your `__init__` method becomes:

```
class MongoConnection():
    mongoconn = None

    def __init__(self, db=None, collection=None, endpoint=None):
        self.mongodb = db
        self.mongocollection = collection
        self.mongoendpoint = endpoint
        MongoConnection.mongoconn = self.__mongo_connect()
```

I don't know if what you are doing is something you should be doing though

Comment: Could you elaborate on your last comment? `I [don't] know if what you are doing is something you should be doing though`

Comment: @MrDuk generally you don't want to manipulate a `Database` instance in your application.  Also using a function will be more efficient if all you need is a *connection handler*.